# How can I dynamically allocate memory for an integer in (objective-c) like (c++)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I dynamically allocate memory for an integer in (objective-c) like (c++) ?

example c++ code:

```
n = 25;

int *p;
p = new int[n];
```

thanks

-this snippet of code will be cycled with dynamically changing sizes (I need to set the size) and will need to be able to declare as integer or long, "NSNumber" may become too slow and use up too much memory in type changes.

Comment: "may become..."? Have you measured this and found it to be too slow/memory intensive?

Comment: Until you test it, measure it, you're better off not making that assumption.

Comment: I have written much code in c and c++.  In CPU and memory intensive applications, switching datatypes is consuming and a bottleneck in ram and cache memory respectively.

Comment: @Kristen - if you have written much code in c and c++, what scares you about the answer suggested by @omz?  That's pretty straightforward c

Comment: You've been given the standard ObjC and C methods for dynamically allocating memory for an integer. Can you explain in more technical detail what your issues are? Maybe that will help us answer your question.

Comment: Unless I know that memory won't be used in a an area, Malloc or Calloc can cause memory conflicts.  I am new to the iPhone and not sure how this would work with other apps or system memory... memory conflicts.  Bottom line... it is looking like I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = 25;
int *p = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
//...
free(p);
```

Comment: I have fear of allocating memory like this.  Depending on iphone it may crash!

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: How is this any more likely to crash than `new int` + `delete`? It's the same thing under the hood.

Comment: @omz: I think you misunderstood the C++ code. It's equivalent to `int n = 25; int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)); *p = n;`. It doesn't allocate space for 25 ints. I'm going to correct it. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: Um, did you mean to write `p = new int[n]`? Because unless I am extremely high right now, that would allocate an array of `n` ints, whereas your snippet allocates a single int with the value of `n`.

Comment: As the original question is changed, I rolled back to my version.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is this assumption:

> "NSNumber" may become too slow and use up too much memory in type changes.

I would recommend using `NSNumber` until you have empirical evidence *proving* that the object wrapper is causing a bottleneck in your code.  Until then, you're prematurely optimizing.

The general rule is:

1. Make it work.
2. Make it fast.

You're trying to reverse those steps.  Don't.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSNumber* myNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1234];
// ...
[myNumber release];
```